# Awareness API: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 15

Tags: android, google-awareness

In my `onCreate` I call the following function to detect the weather.

```
private void detectWeather() {
        if( !checkLocationPermission() ) {
            return;
        }

        Awareness.getSnapshotClient(this).getWeather()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<WeatherResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(WeatherResponse weatherResponse) {
                        Weather weather = weatherResponse.getWeather();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Testing", "Could not get weather: " + e);
                    }
                });
    }
```

In my Manifest file I have added the following meta data and permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.awareness.API_KEY"
    android:value="MYKEY"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="MYKEY"/>
```

And in my Gradle file I've added the following dependencies.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:+'
```

The app launches fine and gets to the awareness API, however it throws the following error in the log: `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 15`. I can't really find the explanation for this error in the documentation nor on Google/Stackoverflow. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you find what was wrong?

Comment: I found that the Error code 15 is for TIMEOUT.See: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes

Comment: Yes, according to the docs at: https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/get-started @ArghadipDasCEO

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, weather and place is now deprecated in the Google Awareness API.

An alternative is the [NumberEight SDK](https://www.numbereight.me/our-tech), which can do a lot more than Awareness (although no regioning is available at the time of writing).

It performs a wide variety of context recognition tasks on both iOS and Android including:

- Real-time physical activity detection
- Current place categories
- Motion detection
- Reachability
- Local weather

It can also record user context for reports and analysis via the online portal.

To quickly receive weather updates in Java, you would write:

```
NumberEight ne = new NumberEight();

ne.onWeatherUpdated(
    new NumberEight.SubscriptionCallback<NEWeather>() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdated(@NonNull Glimpse<NEWeather> glimpse) {
            Log.d("CurrentWeather", glimpse.getMostProbable().toString());
        }
    });
```

Here are some [iOS](https://gitlab.com/numbereight/iOSExample) and [Android](https://gitlab.com/numbereight/AndroidExample) example projects.

*Disclosure: I'm one of the developers.*